# query on interpreting of the data

Tags: regression, logistic, dataset, interpretation

I am trying to understand the result of a logistic regression where the predictor variables are also categorical. I am totally unsure how bad fit is the model to the data and so I am putting the summary value. Given the z values doe s it mean that the model fits well?

```
glm(formula = success ~ HO.FLG.f - 1, family = "binomial", data = tt)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-0.8216  -0.8151  -0.8151   1.5897   1.6033  

Coefficients:
           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
HO.FLG.fBB -0.91258    0.11392  -8.011 1.14e-15 ***
HO.FLG.fFH -0.95650    0.13322  -7.180 6.97e-13 ***
HO.FLG.fHO -0.96141    0.32609  -2.948   0.0032 ** 
HO.FLG.fRQ -0.93127    0.04055 -22.969  < 2e-16 ***

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
    Null deviance: 5136.2  on 3705  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 4411.7  on 3701  degrees of freedom
AIC: 4419.7
```

Answer (score 0):

You have specified a model with the intercept set to 0. The coefficients (Estimate in the table) are the log odds for each level of the factor HO.FLG.f. To get the probabilities, you can do like this:

```
# estimated coefficient for HO.FLG.fBB used to calculate probability of success for HO.FLG.fBB
exp(-0.91258)/(1+exp(-0.91258))
0.2864722
```

So the probability for success in the BB group is 28.6 percent. Z-value is simply estimate/standard error for each level of the factor and is used to calculate p-value. In this case, when excluding the intercept, I'm not sure how the p-value should be interpreted.

The standard way of doing this is to not set the intercept to 0 and use one of the factor levels as the reference category to which the others are compared:

```
glm(formula = success ~ HO.FLG.f, family = "binomial", data = tt)
```

Can you please run this model and update your question?